# Help needed: ERC20 token "BIGTIME" sent to ERC20 smart contract that accepts USDC, BTC, ETH, MANA

Tags: erc-20, tokens, addresses, smart-contract-wallets, recovery

Recently there was a launch of a token called "BIGTIME" (ERC20) from Bigtime Studios (web3 game) listed on a DEX, which I bought tokens from and transferred to the games smart contract to be accessible in-game. However, they have one contract address for the USDC/BTC/ETH/MANA deposits on ERC20 and another address for BIGTIME tokens on ERC20. I was unaware of this and sent the BIGTIME tokens to the address for USDC/BTC/ETH/MANA deposits.

Since both wallets/smart contracts are on the ERC20 chain, should it not be possible to retrieve the tokens that were deposited to the wrong address?
The game Bigtime launched the token and is also owner of the contracts, using Circle as payment solution provider.

I hope someone will help guide me, since the customer support is not being responsive.
Will make sure to upvote a qualified answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the contract addresses that you sent the tokens to, and the one you meant to send to? In cases where you send tokens to the wrong address, it usually means they are lost forever, unfortunately. However, we can check the contract code if you share the addresses, to see if there is any chance of recovery.

Answer (score 0):

If they were sent to an EOA, your only hope would be to ask the account to send them back, but in your case, you sent the tokens to a smart contract.

Tokens sent to the wrong contract address are likely lost forever unless you get lucky and the incorrect contract address that received the tokens has a way to withdraw them.

*without seeing the contract code it's impossible to tell whether or not the tokens are recoverable*

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the contract addresses that you sent the tokens to, and the one you meant to send to? In cases where you send tokens to the wrong address, it usually means they are lost forever, unfortunately. However, we can check the contract code if you share the addresses, to see if there is any chance of recovery